Read Timeout when trying to reach Indian page
I'm trying to reach page: https://meritindia.in . The site doesn't open for me in my current location, but a friend from India confirmed that it works fine for him. I tried to set some proxy for my request ( found something there: http://free-proxy.cz/en/proxylist/country/IN/https/ping/all ), but no luck. Is there a way [apart from vpn] to reach that page?
A piece of Python code that I'm using:
import requests

proxies = {
    'https': '125.99.106.250:3128'
}

url = "https://meritindia.in"
response = requests.get(url, timeout=30, proxies=proxies)
print(response.status_code)


Is there a way to reach that page? Yes, as your friend confirms. If it doesn't want to give you an answer based on geolocation or even browser identification, there's little you can do about it, apart from changing the server code. Maybe you talk to the site operators first?

if your proxy is a http proxy this will work for you.
import requests

proxy_url = "http://125.99.106.250:3128"

proxies = {
    'http': proxy_url,
    'https': proxy_url 
}

url = "https://meritindia.in"
response = requests.get(url, timeout=30, proxies=proxies)
print(response.status_code)

otherwise just change the proxy_url to https://125.99.106.250:3128 or socks://125.99.106.250:3128 (you get the idea what i mean).

Its really hard to answer your question without an http response code.
I would use the below code to retest and debug further:
import requests
from requests.exceptions import RequestException

proxies = {
    'https': '125.99.106.250:3128'  # Example proxy, replace with another if needed
}

url = "https://meritindia.in"
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3'
}

try:
    response = requests.get(url, timeout=30, proxies=proxies, headers=headers)
    response.raise_for_status()  # Raise HTTPError for bad responses
    print(response.status_code)
    print(response.text)  
except RequestException as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

